# synchronous http/https request from browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, firefox-addon, synchronous

I have an HTTPS server that responds to every request from the browser extensions like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc.

I need only a Synchronous way to request the server and get the response because based on the response I have to do the next task in the extension. The next task is fully dependent on the server response.

The problem I am facing currently is how to do a Synchronous request to the server.
I was using **XMLHttpRequest** to request but since the synchronous way is disabled for this XMLHttpRequest so now not allowing Synchronous requests using this method.

Also tried to **fetch** method in the background page but still didn't get the way to do the synchronous way.

**Then** **I thought of this approach:**

send a request in a function and call this function from the event handler.

make a while loop after the server request part and check for the response.
And if the response received or in case of any error or custom timeout( For eg. max time in while loop is 15 sec) then break the loop.

But now the problem is that the response is only received out of a while loop. i.e once the while loop is ended then only getting called function's return value *while the server returns the response much before ending the while loop*

Code for this approach:

```
function doRequest(fileName){
        
        const MaxTimeOutTime = 10000 // millisec
        var tempWaitTime = 0;
        var response = "";
        var timeoutFlag = 0;
        var responseFlag = 0;

        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // const baseUrl = "https://127.0.0.1:8081/post";       
        req.timeout = MaxTimeOutTime;

        console.log("Sending Request to server....");
        req.open("POST", baseUrl, true); // 3rd param for Synchronous/Asynchronous request, false means synchronous
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
        await req.send(fileName);
    
        req.ontimeout = function (e){
            console.log("Timeout occured for url : " + baseUrl);
            timeoutFlag = 1;
        }
        
        req.onerror =  function(e) {
            console.log("Error occured in xmlHttpRequest, StatusCode: " + req.status);
            timeoutFlag = 1;
        }

        req.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
            console.log("Request Status code: " + this.status);
            responseFlag = 1;
            if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
                response = req.responseText;
                console.log("Got response from server: " + req.responseText);
            }
        }

        var count = 0;
        var sleepTime = 100;
        
        while(timeoutFlag === 0 && responseFlag === 0){

            tempWaitTime = tempWaitTime + sleepTime;
            sleep(sleepTime);
            console.log(++count + ".waited for "+ sleepTime + " milisec!");

            if(tempWaitTime >= MaxTimeOutTime){
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log("Now Returning File:FilePath: " + fileName + ":" + response);
        return response;
    }

//Event handler        
 function handleChange(ev){

   //some existing code ...
   
   var retVal = doRequest("arg");
   
   //Next Task dependent on retVal   

 }
```

**Note**: The server returns the response within 0-4 sec.

so Is there any way to do the synchronous request from chrome/Firefox extensions?

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Is the fetch api not available in extensions?

Comment: @Dani I tried it as well but it is also asynchronous.

Comment: 1) You **can** use synchronous XMLHttpRequest, it's not disabled. 2) In JavaScript `sleep` won't work.

Comment: @wOxxOm  synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecated on the main thread. It throws an Error in the extension part. For sleep, I have implemented it

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean "disabled" so you can use it. As for `sleep`, I meant it consumes 100% CPU to block the page so it's terrible.

Comment: Also note, since JavaScript is single-threaded, the code that changes timeoutFlag and responseFlag in req.onreadystatechange will never run so your `while` loop will be infinite.

Comment: Your problem is solvable using then() or async/await with fetch. There should be some tutorials available on the Net.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I use synchronous XMLHttpRequest then on the extension page it throws ERROR with red color. That's why I cannot use it.

Comment: I've just tried and it works in an extension page just like it should. 1) What is the exact error text you're seeing? 2) Are you modifying `content_security_policy` in manifest.json?

Comment: @wOxxOm No, I am not modifying content_security_policy  in manifest.json. "Errors" written with red color shows in chrome://extensions/ page of that extension and the exact error is in this image link: https://imgur.com/a/yN9jNXl

Comment: It's not red, it's yellow-orange, and like I said it works, you can ignore the warning.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's Red on the main extension page and yellow-orange on the details page of that extension. screenshots:  https://imgur.com/a/j3CdY3a

Comment: That label is always red. Like I said, ignore it. Synchronous XHR works.